# Autofac: ITenantIdentificationStrategy with RouteValues

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm having issues making multitenancy work. I've tried to follow the sample [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/tree/develop/samples) and can't see what my implementation is doing differently.

The tenants are identified by a routing parameter in the address field. This seems to work without issues (calling TryIdentifyTenant returns the correct one). I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1, together with Autofac.AspNetCore-Multitenant v3.0.1 and Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection v6.0.0.

I have made a simplification of the code (which is tested and still doesn't work). Two tenants are configured, "terminal1" and "terminal2". The output should differ depending on the tenant. However, it always returns the base implementation. In the example below, inputing "https://localhost/app/terminal1" returns "base : terminal1" and "https://localhost/app/terminal2" returns "base : terminal2". It should return "userhandler1 : terminal1" and "userhandler2 : terminal2".

HomeController:

```cs
     public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserHandler userHandler;
        private readonly TerminalResolverStrategy terminalResolverStrategy;

        public HomeController(IUserHandler userHandler, TerminalResolverStrategy terminalResolverStrategy)
        {
            this.userHandler = userHandler;
            this.terminalResolverStrategy = terminalResolverStrategy;
        }

        public string Index()
        {
            terminalResolverStrategy.TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenant);
            return userHandler.ControllingVncUser + " : " + (string)tenant;
        }
    }
```

UserHandler:

```cs
public interface IUserHandler
    {
        public string ControllingVncUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserHandler : IUserHandler
    {
        public UserHandler()
        {
            ControllingVncUser = "base";
        }

        public string ControllingVncUser { get; set; }
    }


    public class UserHandler1 : IUserHandler
    {
        public UserHandler1()
        {
            ControllingVncUser = "userhandler1";
        }

        public string ControllingVncUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserHandler2 : IUserHandler
    {
        public UserHandler2()
        {
            ControllingVncUser = "userhandler2";
        }

        public string ControllingVncUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Startup:

```cs
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

           public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAutofacMultitenantRequestServices();
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<TerminalResolverStrategy>();
            builder.RegisterType<UserHandler>().As<IUserHandler>();
        }

        public static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
        {
            var strategy = new TerminalResolverStrategy(
                container.Resolve<IOptions<TerminalAppSettings>>(), 
                container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>());

            var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);

            mtc.ConfigureTenant("terminal1", b => b.RegisterType<UserHandler1>().As<IUserHandler>());
            mtc.ConfigureTenant("terminal2", b => b.RegisterType<UserHandler2>().As<IUserHandler>());

            return mtc;
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{terminal}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
}
```

Program:

```cs
        public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory(Startup.ConfigureMultitenantContainer))
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

ITenantIdentificationStrategy:

```cs
        public class TerminalResolverStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
    {
        public IHttpContextAccessor Accessor { get; private set; }

        private readonly TerminalAppSettings settings;

        public TerminalResolverStrategy(
            IOptions<TerminalAppSettings> options,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
            )
        {
            Accessor = httpContextAccessor;
            settings = options.Value;
        }

        public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object terminal)
        {
            HttpContext httpCtx = Accessor.HttpContext;//
            terminal = null;
            try
            {
                if (httpCtx != null &&
                    httpCtx.Request != null &&
                    httpCtx.Request.RouteValues != null &&
                    httpCtx.Request.RouteValues.ContainsKey("terminal"))
                {
                    string requestedTerminal = httpCtx.Request.RouteValues["terminal"].ToString();
                    bool terminalExists = settings.Terminals.ContainsKey(requestedTerminal);
                    if (terminalExists)
                    {
                        terminal = requestedTerminal;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {}
            return terminal != null;
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried not making a custom multitenant container? In ConfigureMultitenantContainer what is "full?" Have you tried simplifying things and getting basics to work without all the extra non-standard config setup you have? (PLEASE update the question, don't put all this stuff in comments here.)

Comment: @TravisIllig I now realize that multitenancy doesn't seem to work at all. I have updated and clarified the example... i really can't see what i'm doing differently from the sample on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after having identified the tenant identification as the problem, it seems like RouteValues isn't resolved with the HttpContext until later in the request chain. Thus, no tenant gets resolved. It seems to me like a bug in .NET Core. The problem got bypassed by using the request path instead:

```
public class TerminalResolverStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
{

    private readonly TerminalAppSettings settings;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public TerminalResolverStrategy(
        IOptions<TerminalAppSettings> options,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
        )
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        settings = options.Value;
    }

    public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object terminal)
    {
        var httpCtx = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        terminal = null;
        try
        {
            if (httpCtx != null)
            {
                string thisPath = httpCtx.Request.Path.Value;
                var allTerminals = settings.Terminals.GetEnumerator();
                while (allTerminals.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (thisPath.Contains(allTerminals.Current.Key)) { 
                    terminal = allTerminals.Current.Key;
                    return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Multitenancy doesn't seem to work at all" is a somewhat ambiguous statement that's hard to address. Unfortunately, I don't *personally* have the time to download all of your example code and try to repro the whole thing and debug into it and see exactly what's wrong. Perhaps someone else does. However, I can offer some tips as to places I'd look and things I'd try to see what's up.

**Tenant ID strategy set up twice.** I see in `Startup.ConfigureContainer` that there's a `builder.RegisterType<TerminalResolverStrategy>();` line - that's going to register your strategy type as instance-per-dependency, so every time it's needed it'll be resolved fresh. I also see in `Startup.ConfigureMultitenantContainer` that you're manually instantiating the strategy that gets used by the multitenant container. There's a non-zero possibility that something is getting messed up there. I would pick one way to get that done - either register the strategy or manually create it - and I'd make sure that thing is a stateless singleton. (It's not registered in the example.)

**Route pattern possibly questionable.** I see the route pattern you have registered looks like this: `{terminal}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`. I also see your URLs look like this: `https://localhost/app/terminal1` Have you stepped into your tenant ID strategy to make sure the route parsing mechanism works right? That is, `app` isn't being picked up as the `terminal` value? Route parsing/handling can be tricky.

**Possibly bad settings.** The tenant ID strategy only successfully identifies a tenant if there are options that specify that the specific `terminal` value exists. I don't see where any of those options are configured, which means in this repo there are no tenants defined. Your strategy won't identify anything without that.

If it was me, I'd probably start with a breakpoint in that tenant ID strategy and see what's getting resolved and what's not. It seems somewhat complex from an outside perspective and that's where I'd begin. If that is working, then I'd probably also look at cleaning up the registrations so the ID strategy isn't registered twice. Finally, I get the impression that this isn't all the code in the app; I'd probably look at making a super minimal reproduction that's about the size you actually have posted here. I'd then focus on making that minimal repro work; then once it works, I'd figure out what the difference is between the repro and my larger app.

Unfortunately, that's about all I can offer you. As I mentioned, with the current environment and my current workload, I won't be able to actually sit down and reproduce the whole thing with your code. I know the integration works because I have production apps using it; and there are a lot of tests (unit and integration) to validate it works; so the part that isn't working is likely in your code somewhere... and those are the places I'd start.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At least it made me certain that it wasn't anything obvious. As you suspected it was the tenant ID strategy which was faulty. Posted answer below.